# R: Replacing a for-loop with an apply function

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, linear-regression

I managed to apply a linear regression for each subject of my data frame and paste the values into a new dataframe using a *for-loop*. However, I think there should be a more readable way of achieving my result using an apply function, but all my attempts fail. This is how I do it:

```
numberOfFiles <- length(resultsHick$subject)
intslop       <- data.frame(matrix(0,numberOfFiles,4))
intslop       <- rename(intslop,
                        subject   = X1,
                        intercept = X2,
                        slope     = X3,
                        Rsquare   = X4)

cond        <- c(0:3)
allSubjects <- resultsHick$subject

for (i in allSubjects)
    {intslop[i,1] <- i

     yvalues <- t(subset(resultsHick,
                  subject == i, 
                  select = c(H0meanRT, H1meanRT, H2meanRT, H258meanRT)))

     fit        <- lm(yvalues ~ cond)
     intercept  <- fit$coefficients[1]
     slope      <- fit$coefficients[2]
     rsquared   <- summary(fit)$r.squared
     intslop[i,2] <- intercept
     intslop[i,3] <- slope
     intslop[i,4] <- rsquared
     }
```

The result should look the same as

```
> head(intslop)
  subject intercept    slope   Rsquare
1       1  221.3555 54.98290 0.9871209
2       2  259.4947 66.33344 0.9781499
3       3  227.8693 47.28699 0.9537868
4       4  257.7355 80.71935 0.9729132
5       5  197.4659 49.57882 0.9730409
6       6  339.1649 61.63161 0.8213179
...
```

Does anybody know a more readable way of writing this code using an apply function?

Comment: You probably want a combination of dplyr and broom packages. See the vignette here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html

Comment: lmList() in package nlme will do this very nicely.

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions, I will check the packages out.

Answer (score 0):

One common pattern I use to replace for loops that aggregate data.frames is:

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(1:numberOfDataFrames,
         FUN = function(i) {
           print(paste("Processing index:", i)) # helpful to see how slow/fast
           temp_df <- do_some_work[i]
           temp_df$intercept <- 1, etc.
           return(temp_df) # key is to return a data.frame for each index.
         }
  )
)
```